# Notice: Undefined index from line 42 to line 62

Tags: php, search

I've been trying to find and answer to my problem which is my Search code in my php, please help me out. Here's the code of my problem

```
function getPosts()
        {
            $posts = array();
            $posts[0] = $_POST['$id'];
            $posts[1] = $_POST['$studentID'];
            $posts[2] = $_POST['$firstN'];
            $posts[3] = $_POST['$middleN'];
            $posts[4] = $_POST['$lastN'];
            $posts[5] = $_POST['$course'];
            $posts[6] = $_POST['$year'];
            $posts[7] = $_POST['$PoBirth'];
            $posts[8] = $_POST['$address'];
            $posts[9] = $_POST['$birthday'];
            $posts[10] = $_POST['$acr'];
            $posts[11] = $_POST['$gender'];
            $posts[12] = $_POST['$nationality'];
            $posts[13] = $_POST['$mobile'];
            $posts[14] = $_POST['$status'];
            $posts[15] = $_POST['$schoolyear'];
            $posts[16] = $_POST['$guardianN'];
            $posts[17] = $_POST['$guardianM'];
            $posts[18] = $_POST['$relationship'];
            $posts[19] = $_POST['$occupation'];
            $posts[20] = $_POST['$guardianAddress'];

            return $posts;

        }
```

Comment: Can you share your form? How do you call `getPosts()`?

Comment: how to post data to php ?

Comment: Is the name of your input really `$id`? Exactly that, with the dollarsign? I think you ment `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Undefined index mean your code not have an index

Comment: `'$id'` is literally `$id` you need to use double quotes for it to expand to the value, or no quotes.

Comment: You have to wonder where all `$_POST['$vars']`'s are coming from.